# Java sql credential handling

Tags: java, sql, deployment, credentials

What is the recommended way to handle database credentials across a collection of java projects for deployment?  Currently I have a credentials file with each project jar that is manually updated depending on whether the project is deployed into a test or production environment.

Answer (score 0):

Use an outer encrypted file for the credentials. Check for some ciphers regarding crypting file data.